# Пользовательский тип постов WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

С помощью плагина "Pods" создал пользовательский тип постов "gallery" и таксономии к ним "year".
Изображения (посты) и года (категории) вывожу на странице "taxonomy-year.php".

Не могу понять, как вывести ссылку на "gallery" (сейчас выводится отдельно созданная страница) в главном меню сайта, чтобы автоматически открывалась последняя созданная категория, в данном случае с текущим годом?
Сами категории Года имеют класс "active", чтобы понимать в каком году я сейчас нахожусь, как мне сделать, чтобы вместе с этим класс "active" был и у выведенной в главном меню ссылки Галерея, как например у родительских страниц, когда находимся на дочерней?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена путём создания родительской таксономии и выводом её в главном меню.